# Does $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{3yx^3}{x^6+y^2}$ exist?

Tags: calculus, limits

The limit is $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{3yx^3}{x^6+y^2}$
I've tried setting $x=0$ and $y=0$, as well as $x=y$ and $y=x$, but I can't seem to conclude anything.

Comment: Set $y=m\cdot x^3$.

Comment: could you explain why?

Comment: When you ask if something exists and somebody tells you to check an example, it will be a counterexample. Why this counterexample? Because it lets you simplify the term easily.

Comment: The idea behinde Jamals example is that you want to simplify the denumerator and this is the easiest way to do so.

Comment: why the m though?

Comment: You actually don't need to take $m$. You can see LostInSpace's answer below. He just showed that the limit along the paths $y=x$ and $y=x^3$ are different. Hence the limit of the function at $(0,0)$ doesn't exist. Taking the limit along the path $y=mx^3$ results in an expression that depends solely on $m$. From this you can conclude that for different values of $m$, you get different values of the limit, which implies that the limit does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

If the limit exists, no matter how $(x,y) \to (0,0) $ it must be the same. Now assume that you choose $y=mx^3$. Then as $x \to 0$ you have that $(x, y(x)) \to (0,0)$. But
$$
f(x,mx^3 ) = \frac{{3mx^6 }}
{{x^6 \left( {1 + m^2 } \right)}}
$$
thus, as long as $x \neq 0$, you have that
$$
f(x,mx^3 ) = \frac{{3m}}
{{\left( {1 + m^2 } \right)}}
$$
therefore
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} f(x,mx^3 ) = \frac{{3m}}
{{\left( {1 + m^2 } \right)}}
$$
Since this value depends on $m$, the global limit dose not exists.
Of course the choice of the special relation between $y$ and $x$ must be careful.

Answer (score 0):

$$l=\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{3yx^3}{x^6+y^2}$$
For $y=x$ we have:
$$l=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{3x^2}{x^4+1}=0$$
But for $y=x^3$ we have:
$$l=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{3x^6}{2x^6}=\frac 3 2$$
The limit does not exist.